# Why does my Windows 10 OEM have 2 different keys?

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation, license-key

My laptop came pre installed with OEM Windows 10.

To get rid of several bloat-wares that come with oem windows 10, I did  a clean install of Windows 10 using downloaded ISO, installer created on Pen drive using Rufus app.

Due to digital entitlement, it re-activated when online. During the entire process I never had to manually enter any key anywhere due to OEM windows.

I however wonder why apps show me 2 different Windows 10 Keys. Why is it that the OEM Key in BIOS (fetched using OEMKeyFinder app) is different from the Windows 10 key as fetched from Windows installation using Lazesoft Windows Key Finder?

I could not understand the reason for the two different keys. Any clarity would be nice to know.

Comment: Keys are no longer used by Microsoft for activation, keys stored in the OS just tell Microsoft what product version it is. Keys stored in the bios are for OEM recovery media to install the proper product on that particular pc.

Comment: @Moab - License keys are still used for the initial activation.  Microsoft has an entire page dedicated to digital entitlement and when its or isn't applicable.

Comment: Which two applications did you use exactly?  One was `OEMKeyFinder` but you were not clear what the other application was.

Comment: It's Lazesoft Windows Key Finder. Edited the question.